# Определение цвета по кординатам в bmp изображении Borland C++ Builder 6. Есть ли вариант быстрее?

Tags: c++, обработка-изображений, borland-c++

Ниже приведён код как я сейчас у TBitmap определяю цвет по определённой координате изображения, а именно с использованием ->Canvas->Pixels[i][j]. Прочитал что этот метод медленный и действительно работает медленно, на обработку изображения 1366x768 уходит примерно 2 секунды. Можно ли как то определять цвет по координате быстрее?

```
  ggg->LoadFromFile("sssss.bmp");
  for (int i=0;i<1365;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<767;j++) {
      if (ggg->Canvas->Pixels[i][j] == 255) {
        //Memo1->Lines->Add(IntToStr(i)+(AnsiString)" x "+IntToStr(j));
      }
    }
  }
``
```

Comment: "определяю цвет по определённой координате" — так вы перебираете все пиксели или смотрите какой-то конкретный? И - 2 секунды — это при наличии тела цикла или без оного? Т.е. надо выяснить, что именно вас тормозит...

Comment: Обычно BMP картинки через `ScanLine` читают - это в разы быстрее

Comment: Не знакомое слово ScanLine, пока нет времени чтобы ознакомиться с термином в поиске(возможно попозже посмотрю что это). Я уже решил этот вопрос изучив структуру bmp файла в котором каждый пиксель кодируется 3 байтами, то есть цветами RGB. Заполнение пикселей идёт снизу в вверх и слева на право. По скорости метод который я описал отличается не просто в разы а сотни или более раз, то есть быстрее описанного в вопросе.